# i cant find a way to return my 3D setting on

Tags: unity

i just was installing a new virtual box and noticed that my desktop was running on 2D and i cant find a way to return it to 3D.
Its getting hard for me to use some of my applications, need some help

Answer (score 1):

To change to UBUNTU (unity 3D) you have to select the session at log in time by clicking on the circle on the upper right corner of the username screen and then select **UBUNTU**

1. Click on the upper right corner button as you see here-

[image: greeter1]

2. Then you will get the following options(Atleast **UBUNTU** and **UBUNTU 3D** will be definitly be there)

[image: greeter2]

FROM THERE SELECT **UBUNTU**

you will enter Unity 3D

Comment: well the Ubuntu selection is not working to and i don't know what seems to be the problem..

Comment: Try executing the command `unity --reset`

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu will default to 2D if your graphics card does not support 3D acceleration.

I believe you need to enable 3D acceleration in the Virtualbox settings for the VM and install the guest additions. After that if it does not default to 3D, follow Nirmik's instructions.